# How to get the level of a node in binary tree using python?

Tags: python, recursion, data-structures, binary-tree

I tried to implement the binary tree program in python. I want to add one more function to get the level of a specific node.

eg:-

```
    10      # level 0
   /  \
  5   15    # level 1
 / \ 
3   7       # level 2
```

if we search the level of node 3, it should return

```
class BinaryTree:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.data = data
        
    def insert(self, data):
        if self.data == data:
            return
        if self.data<data:
            if self.left:
                self.left.insert(data)
            else:
                self.left = BinaryTree(data)
        else:
            if self.right:
                self.right.insert(data)
            else:
                self.right = BinaryTree(data)
        
    def print_tree(self):
        if self:
            print(self.data)    
        if self.left:
            self.left.print_tree()
        elif self.right:
            self.right.print_tree()
            
    def get_level(self, data, level=0):
        print(type(data))
        level += 1
        if self.data == data:
            return level
        elif self.left and self.right:
            if self.left:
                self.left.get_level(data)
            elif self.right:
                self.right.get_level(data)
        return level
    
    def in_order(self):
        if self:
            #left
            in_order(self.left)
            #root
            print(self.data, '->')
            #right
            in_order(self.right)
```

This is my code for Binary tree. I need to add another function to this class which will tell the **level of a node** after giving the value

For example:

```
def get_level(node):
    #some code
    return level


get_level(10) # returns the level of the node 10
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I can't understand the question. "if we search the level of node 3, it should return" - should return what? And why? "This is my code for Binary tree. I need to add another function to this class which will tell the level of a node after giving the value" Okay, so what is the problem you are encountering? Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822. You are expected to try to break down the problem into logical parts, first. For example, I see that you tagged the question `recursion`. Do you know how that works? How do you intend to use it?

Comment: I already see `def get_level(self, data, level=0):` in the code. Did you try to use it? What happens when you try to use it? How is that different from what is supposed to happen? Did you try to [trace what happens](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) when you use it, and find a problem?

Comment: Also, please read [mre]. We don't need to see working code for the other tree algorithms in order to understand the problem. We only need to see how the tree is represented (i.e.: that the children are named `left` and `right` and that there is a `data` in each node).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
def get_level(self, data, level=0):
    print(type(data))
    level += 1
    if self.data == data:
        return level
    if data > self.data:
        if self.left:
            return self.left.get_level(data,level)
    else:
        if self.right:
            return self.right.get_level(data,level)

    return None
```

For the 10 the level will be 1, for 5 and 15 it is level 2, and for 3 and 7 it is level 3.

for the 0,1,2 levels just remove the "level+=1" line and add a +1 in level variable at the recursion call.

Answer (score 0):

Before getting into your question, there are some issues in your existing code:

- The `insert` method is using the BST property of the tree (good), but is going to the wrong subtree to find the location of the insertion point. The condition `if self.data<data` should be inverted to `if self.data > data`.
- The function `inorder` has recursive calls that call the function not as a method but as a global function. So that means the indentation of this function is wrong. It should be defined outside of the `class`, not inside.

> I need to add another function to this class

You already have that function, but it has these issues:

- The function returns a level, but when you make the recursive call, you ignore that returned value.
- As you never pass the level argument, that level will always start with 0 and so the returned value will always be 1.
- With the `elif self.left and self.right` you ignore the case where a node has *one* child.
- No benefit is taken from the fact that this is a BST, and so both left and right subtrees are traversed, while data can be found by following a single path.

I would suggest to do this without `level` parameter, and let the function return the level as if the given node were the root. The caller can than add 1 *after* the recursive call.

```
    def get_level(self, data):
        if data == self.data:
            return 0
        level = None
        if data < self.data:
            if self.left:
                level = self.left.get_level(data)
        else:
            if self.right:
                level = self.right.get_level(data)
        if level is not None:
            return level + 1
```